# Prove a subgraph is a spanning tree

Tags: graph

> Let T and T' be 2 spanning trees of a connected graph G. Suppose that
>   an arc x is in T but not in T'. Prove that there is an arc y in T'
>   such that (T-{x})∪{y} and (T'-{y})∪{x} are spanning trees in G.

Any ideas how I can prove this? Is there a formal way of proving that a subgraph is a spanning tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and Yes.

You prove a subgraph is a spanning tree by proving that:

1. The subgraph touches all nodes in the graph; and
2. The subgraph is a tree.

   - There is exactly one path between any two nodes.

Since `T` and `T'` are both spanning trees, you know that there is exactly one path between any two nodes in `T` or `T'` and that both `T` and `T'` touch every node in `G`.

If you remove `arc x` from `T`, then you get two trees. Let's call them `T0` and `T1`. Since `T'` touches every node, then there must exist an `arc y` in `T'` such that one endpoint is in `T0` and the other is in `T1`.

Both `arc x` and `arc y` are arcs that connect `T0` to `T1`. Since connecting two trees produces a tree and `T0` and `T1` cover all nodes in `G`, `(T-{x})∪{y}` and `(T'-{y})∪{x}` are spanning trees.

As you may have noticed, I didn't go into much detail on the actual proof and just gave an overview. You will need to prove:

1. Removing `arc x` from `T` produces two trees, `T0` and `T1`, that share no nodes and no arcs;
2. There must exist an `arc y` in `T'` which connects `T0` to `T1`;
3. Removing `arc y` from `T'` produces two trees that cover the same nodes as `T0` and `T1`; and
4. Connecting two trees with an arc produces a tree.

plus some other small things to glue it all together into one coherent answer, but these 4 things are the core items that need to be shown. The other things are all quite easy to infer once you have these things proven.

Good luck with what I assume to be a piece of homework.